# Don't see why I'm getting 'numpy.ndarray object not callable' error?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, typeerror

I have a code that uses `numpy` and `hermval` along with multiple functions to compute `psi` at the end for given parameters. But I keep getting the error `numpy.ndarray object not callable`, and I really don't see why this is happening. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
from numpy.linalg import eigh
from numpy.polynomial.hermite import hermval

def matrices(N, lam):
    H_0 = np.zeros([N+1, N+1])
    x_four_matrix = np.zeros([N+1, N+1])
    for n in range(N+1):
        for m in range(N+1):
            if n == m:
                H_0[n][m] = n + 0.5
                x_four_matrix[n][m] = (6.0*n**2 + 6.0*n + 3.0)/4.0
            elif n == m-2:
                x_four_matrix[n][m] = np.sqrt((n+1)*(n+2))*(n+1.5)
            elif n == m+2:
                x_four_matrix[n][m] = (n-0.5)*np.sqrt(n*(n-1))
            elif n == m-4:
                x_four_matrix[n][m] = np.sqrt((n+1)*(n+2)*(n+3)*(n+4))/4.0
            elif n == m+4:
                x_four_matrix[n][m] = np.sqrt((n-3)*(n-2)*(n-1)*n)/4.0
    return H_0, x_four_matrix

def H_lam(N, lam):
    return matrices(N, lam)[0] + lam*matrices(N, lam)[1]

# Solve for eigenvalues (energies)
def lowest_eigenvals(N, n, lam):
    lowest_eigs = []
    eigenvals = eigh(H_lam(N, lam))[0]
    eigenvals.sort()
    for i in range(n):
        lowest_eigs.append(eigenvals[i])
    return lowest_eigs

# Solve for eigenvectors
def lowest_eigenvectors(N, n, lam):
    lowest_vecs = []
    for i in range(len(lowest_eigenvals(N, n, lam))):
        for j in range(len(eig(H_lam(N, lam))[0])):
            if lowest_eigenvals(N, n, lam)[i] == eigh(H_lam(N, lam))[0][j]:
                lowest_vecs.append(eigh(H_lam(N, lam))[1][j])
    return np.array(lowest_vecs)

def N_coeff(i):
    return 1.0/np.sqrt(2**i*math.factorial(i)*np.sqrt(np.pi))

# for E_0 (first eigenfunction):
def psi(x, lowest_eigenvectors, i):
    herm_coeffs = [element*N_coeff(i) for element in lowest_eigenvectors(N, n, lam)[i]]
    return np.exp((x**2)/2.0)*hermval(x, herm_coeffs)

print [element*N_coeff(0) for element in lowest_eigenvectors(100, 4, 0.1)[0]]
print psi(1.0, lowest_eigenvectors(100, 4, 1.0), 0) # for lambda = 1
```

And then with my last `print` statement here, I get `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable` coming from the `herm_coeffs` line in my last function. But I'm not sure why this is happening, since the second to last `print` statement prints correctly! What is going on here?

Here is the traceback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-350-04692f269a26> in <module>()
     13 # print [element*N_coeff(0) for element in lowest_eigenvectors(100, 4, 0.1)[0]]
     14 
---> 15 print psi(1.0, lowest_eigenvectors(100, 4, 0.1), 0)

<ipython-input-350-04692f269a26> in psi(x, lowest_eigenvectors, i)
      7 # for E_0 (first eigenfunction):
      8 def psi(x, lowest_eigenvectors, i):
----> 9     herm_coeffs = [element*N_coeff(i) for element in lowest_eigenvectors(N, n, lam)[i]]
     10     return np.exp((x**2)/2.0)*hermval(x, herm_coeffs)
     11 

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: The error means that you are trying use a `numpy` array as though it were a function (a callable).  That could because you mistakenly used `()` to index the array.  Or what you think is a function, is really an array, due to some variable name confusion earlier in the code.

Comment: Can you please provide the traceback?

Comment: @Scott see new edit

Comment: Your parameter name clashes with the name of your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off what @Scott suggested, I think `psi` should be changed to:

```
def psi(x, vectors, i):
    herm_coeffs = [element*N_coeff(i) for element in vectors[i]]
    return np.exp((x**2)/2.0)*hermval(x, herm_coeffs)

print psi(1.0, lowest_eigenvectors(100, 4, 1.0), 0)
```

In other words, you calculate `vectors = lowest_eigenvectors(100, 4, 1.0)`, and pass that to `psi`.  Even if you got this array vs. function naming correct, using:

```
lowest_eigenvectors(N, n, lam)
```

in `psi` would be a problem because `N, n, lam` are not defined either in the function or globally.

I wonder if that function could be further simplified with:

```
herm_coeffs = N_coeff(i)*vectors[i]
```

Answer (score 3):

`lowest_eigenvectors` parameter name in function `psi` is clashing with function `lowest_eigenvectors`.

**EDIT:** it looks like you don't need to pass `psi` the function `lowest_eigenvectors` since the `psi` function is within the same [lexical scope](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping) as `lowest_eigenvectors`.

Comment: I see. So do I need to get rid of the parameters of `lowest_eigenvectors` inside the `psi` function? I know it's possible to call functions within other functions, so is that the issue here?

Comment: You can just rename the parameter to something other than `lowest_eigenvectors`.

Comment: But I do need that parameter to be the output of the `lowest_eigenvectors` function.